# IS Network automation kills carries of network Engineers?

Tags: network, networking, internet

Iam working as network engineer since long time and i enjoying working same . But now i am afraid after listening of network automation .Is network automation kills jobs of network engineer across globe .

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based

Comment: Until we have AI and robots, I think my job is safe. Much of the automation in my life is stuff I've created so I'm not typing the same commands over and over. As Zac answered, we still need humans to design and build networks. Automation is helpful on a day-to-day basis, but people still have to install hardware, run cables, plan address spaces, and think about the future.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent. However, networks tend to grow, so much of the automation gain is eaten up by growth.

Also, the more skilled you are the less automation can take over your job. After all, someone has to engineer and maintain the automation - and of course, create the architecture, do the troubleshooting, ...